# Is it possible to update a google sheet with a firebase realtime database whose nodes are strings and not integers?

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a very basic gs script with two for loops to fill a google sheet with the data that is stored in a firebase realtime database. I know the script is simple and weak and I could map things.
Here is the script (first page of google results):

```js
function getAllData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var firebaseUrl = "yourDBurl";

  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);

  var dataSet = [base.getData()];
  

  // the following lines will depend on the structure of your data
  var rows = [],
      data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    for (j = 0; j < dataSet[i].length; j++) {
      //check your data type in firebase and update accordingly 
     
    rows.push([data[j].id,data[j].batch,data[j].name]);
    }
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, rows.length,3 );
  dataRange.setValues(rows); 
}
```

Despite being simple it did work for what I was doing. That is until I decided to rename the parent nodes with SKUs instead of the implicit sequence 0,1,2,3,...

When the database is structured this way:

[image: DB implicit structure]

Firebase creates such a structure:

```js
[
  {
    "batch": "batch1",
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "batch": "batch2",
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "batch": "batch3",
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  }
]
```

Now if I choose to add a single node is named (the key is now a string) as such :

[image: DB with string as a key]

This is the tree that firebase produces by default:

```js
{
  "0": {
    "batch": "batch1",
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  "1": {
    "batch": "batch2",
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  "2": {
    "batch": "batch3",
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  },
  "bob": {
    "batch": "batchbob",
    "id": "idbob",
    "name": "namebob"
  }
}
```

Notice I don't have a square brackets`[]` anymore, but some array in curly braces `{}` with items that my function
`FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl).getData()` cannot iterate over and as a result my rows.length is nil and my list "rows" is empty.
Is there a tweak I can do or a different function with parameters I can use instead of `getData()` that would enable me to continue using this two loops script?

The firebase doc has limited information about googleApps scripts unlike java and I am absolutely unfamiliar with .gs fundamental inner workings. I tried to alter how I defined my variables and using other functions such as `getAllData()` with parameters without much hope and so far I haven't had any success.

I'm adding my very naive attempt trying to implement the first suggestion:

```js
function getAllData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var firebaseUrl = "yourDBurl";

  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);

  var dataSet = [base.getData()];
  

  // the following lines will depend on the structure of your data
 var rows = [],
      data = [];
        values =[]
  for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(dataSet)) {
      data =  Object.values(dataSet)
      //console.log(data);
    for (j of data) {
        values = Object.values(j)
        for (k of values)
      rows.push(Object.values(k));
      // console.log(rows);
    }
  }


  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1, rows.length,3 );
  dataRange.setValues(rows); 
}
```

The code is now working but I'm still perplexed by the indexing. Will mark resolved once this is figured. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you've been depending on is Firebase Realtime Database array-coercion logic, which it applies when:

- All keys can be parsed as numbers
- The first key is a sufficiently low number
- All keys are close to each other (i.e. you can skip some numbers, but not many)

When you added a non-numeric key you broke that first requirement, and thus Firebase will stop coercing the data to an array and will isntead return the actual keys of the child properties in an object.

---

You will either have to remove the non-numeric key so that the existing code works again, or alternatively update the code to work with the non-array/object structure that you get back now.

One way to do the latter is to iterate over [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataSet)) {
  rows.push([key, value]);
}
```

A working code-sample for this:

```js
const dataSet = {
  "0": {
    "batch": "batch1",
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  "1": {
    "batch": "batch2",
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  "2": {
    "batch": "batch3",
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  },
  "bob": {
    "batch": "batchbob",
    "id": "idbob",
    "name": "namebob"
  }
}

let rows = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataSet)) {
  rows.push([key, value]);
}

console.log(rows);
```

Comment: thank you. I did read about this logic at some point. It explains the WHY. What I'm trying to do is to display my info like anyone would do with an excel/GS page. Maybe I still don't understand how it works but it seems the function you pointed out returns 0 as the key for the root and the entire file as the value. Do I have a way to sort things out from this point ? I get {value={2={batch=batch2, id=id2, name=name2}, bob={name=namebob, id=idbob, batch=batchbob}, 3={name=name3, batch=batch3, id=id3}, 1={name=name1, batch=batch1, id=id1}}} for the value. Also it seems the indexing is random.

Comment: First off: does the explanation of how Firebase interprets consecutive numeric values as array indexes make sense, and does it explain why things fall apart when you add a non-numeric key? --- "I did read about this logic at some point" Yet you don't mention that in your question, which is all we have to go on when trying to help you. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

----

If you're having a hard time making the code I shared in my answer work, considering showing what you tried in your question, including the error you get.

Comment: it does help to understand. I think it was written that the nodes should start at a low integers value and that 50% of them should be integers or consecutive something like that in the doc. I'm aware that getData() breaks down. Object.entries() seems more appropriate as it targets objects within the {} but doing a rows.push([value]) gives back my whole "tree" into one cell and not in the same order every time instead of the original code which would give one value per column (second loop) per key (first loop). All I'm saying is [value] is not  the child anymore and [key]looses meaning to me.

Comment: Your code is now nesting loops, which wasn't there originally. Also note that your original code did `rows.push([data.id, data.name])`. So those are the things I then mimicked in my answer. --- I updated my answer to show working code for how to loop over the properties of the object you get back. If you have another level outside of the JSON you shared, you'll have to loop over that too.

Comment: thank you very much for your contribution though as I tried to explain while your example in .js mimicking the DB and pulling the console seems to fulfill the task of iterating over objects, If I try to implement it in a google sheet script (.gs) it outputs the key 0 in the first column and the entire set of objects in the second column with no indexing. I guess I don't know how to display this information in the original way I did it. You are right I corrected the mistakenly uploaded code.

Comment: I needed  Object.entries() to target elements but  I did not understand I also needed  Object.keys() and Object.values() to split my data into something useful. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.